# Using polymer in Java or NodeJS

Tags: java, javascript, html, node.js, polymer

I would like to generate static HTML5 pages, defining my own tags and rendering more complex HTML in the generated pages.

I like the [polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) architecture approach to define new sets of tags.

When I want to generate my pages, I'm not in a browser, so I can use Java or NodeJS engines to compute the final HTML pages (from a console for instance).

To sum up, I want to define my own tag libraries using the [polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) approach, code some HTML using those new tags, and "print" the result DOM in a static HTML file, running all that from a console program (using Java or NodeJS).

Does somebody know how to do so?

It seems I must have some DOM interpreters, and I know that in Java I can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), but it will probably lack some JavaScript interpreter? Can NodeJS do that more simply?

Comment: Polymer relies on being integrated with the browser environment at runtime; it's not about "generating" HTML.

Comment: Yes I know that. I also know that it modifies the DOM at runtime in the browser. If you can then "print" that DOM, then you have a new static HTML page. That's what I would want...

Comment: So if I understood you, you want to do kind of compiling polymer code and converting it to non-webcomponent code?

Comment: Yes, as polymer actually does in the DOM

Comment: Maybe try using phantomjs? http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: Good idea, I will have a look at phantomjs, thanks

Comment: checkout this blogpost http://java-is-the-new-c.blogspot.de/2015/07/polymer-webcomponents-served-with-java.html